# Grails : Creating dynamic tables and PDF generation

Tags: grails, groovy

I am new to Grails environment and kinda running short of ideas to create a page.

The Grails app am working is on using version 2.3.6

There are multiple domain classes in this app. I need to create a page with multiple tables based upon properties from different domain classes.

All the information in the tables can be added a text/string. So this part is pretty simple.

The difficult part is, am not sure how many rows of data is going to be in each tables. This will purely depend on data retrieved from each domain object.

I know for sure that there are going to be multiple tables.

As this is going to be dynamic table creation, is there any better ways of doing it? Does using AJAX make table creation more faster and efficient?

Once all the data is populated in different tables, it should let the user generate a PDF report. How can this be achieved in Grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of rows in a table depends on data returned from the controller, then you'll probably want to use the GSP `each` tag and iterate over the list of data, printing out a table row for each item.

Reference for this tag in version 2.3.6 can be found here: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.6/ref/Tags/each.html

As for generating PDF, it depends how you want to do it but there are many grails plugins available that might help you. Check out:
http://grails.org/plugins/search?q=pdf